# Native JavaScript innerHTML not getting the content created by vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this div that I want to pull the contents

```
<div id="print" ref="print_data">
   <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
</div>
```

and tried to pull the contents using the native innerHTML

```
console.log( document.querySelector('#print').innerHTML );
```

I tried also refs

```
console.log( this.$refs['print_data'].innerHTML );
```

and I can't see the content of the #print div, but I can see the `age` content created by vue on the page.

Here's the whole code

```
<div id="app">
   <div id="print" ref="print_data">
      <span>{{ age }}</span>
      <span>{{ name }}</span>
   </div>
   <button @click="print">Print</button>
   <button @click="print2">Print 2</button>
   <button @click="print3">Print 3</button>
   <button @click="print4">Print 4</button>
</div>

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      age: 12,
      name: ''
   },
   methods: {
      print: function(){
         this.name = 'test';
         console.log(document.querySelector('#print').innerHTML);
         // returns HTML but 'age' is missing, no content generated by vue
      }),
      print2: function(){
         this.name = 'test';
         console.log(this.$refs['print_data'].innerHTML);
         // returns HTML but 'age' is missing, no content generated by vue
      }),
      print3: function(){
         this.name = 'test2';
         console.log(this.$refs['print_data'].content.innerHTML);
         // returns error
      }),
      print4: function(){
         this.name = 'test3';
         console.log(this.$refs['print_data'].toString());
         // returns [object HTMLDivElement]
      }),
   }
});
```

Comment: where did you log that content?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim to html page

Comment: I mean where do you have `console.log( document.querySelector('#print').innerHTML );` in your code?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim im confused. above post imply my testing activity so yes.

Comment: please share the whole code that wraps the snippet above

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim kindly check above. I updated.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcrowxyz/pen/yLvpLEP)
The first three functions have values that you want !

Comment: @PouyaM whats in there? it just a plain vue

Comment: @JuliverGalleto The problem is that you change your value in the function and want to read it from DOM, which is not updated yet!

Answer (score 0):

I found out its because vue is not finish updating the DOM resulting the issue, instead I use, the `$nextTick()` and wrap it with `async`

```
( async function(){
    await _this.$nextTick().then(() => {                      
        console.log(document.getElementById("print").innerHTML);      
    });       
})()
```

and its working now.

Comment: The approach is correct but the code is really hacky and redundant. It's either `await this.$nextTick(); console.log(...)` if you use promises, and `this.$nextTick(() => { console.log(...) })` if you don't